# Checking each row of DataGridView for information quickly

Tags: .net, vb.net, datagridview

I am trying to assign a picture to a column on each row of my dataset. The data is held in a `DataGridView`.

When the form is loaded, the `DataGridView` is populated and then each row is checked to produce a status, the image that corresponds to this status is then loaded into the first column.

The code below works fine, but for a 2000 row dataset, it's taking a good 30+ seconds to populate the images, which is far too long. Is there something I can do to speed this up, or an alternative approach to ease the loading on the system?

```
For i = 0 To dgvViewOrders.RowCount - 1

            If dgvViewOrders.Rows(i).Cells("DepositPaid").Value = False Then
                dgvViewOrders.Rows(i).Cells("ColImg").Value = My.Resources.WaitingForDeposit_25

            ElseIf dgvViewOrders.Rows(i).Cells("DepositPaid").Value = True And CDate(dgvViewOrders.Rows(i).Cells("DateProcessed").Value).AddDays(20) < Now And dgvViewOrders.Rows(i).Cells("AllMaterialsDelivered").Value = False Then
                dgvViewOrders.Rows(i).Cells("ColImg").Value = My.Resources.ItemsRequireOrdering_25

            ElseIf dgvViewOrders.Rows(i).Cells("AllMaterialsDelivered").Value = False Then
                dgvViewOrders.Rows(i).Cells("ColImg").Value = My.Resources.WaitingForDelivery_25

            Else
                If dgvViewOrders.Rows(i).Cells("FullPaid").Value = True Then
                    dgvViewOrders.Rows(i).Cells("ColImg").Value = My.Resources.Checked_25
                Else
                    dgvViewOrders.Rows(i).Cells("ColImg").Value = My.Resources.WaitingForPayment_25
                End If

            End If



        Next
```

Edit: I should also note that I can't easily change the database headers to include somewhere to store this status, so it has to be done on the fly when loaded.

**Update 1**

Using `Jinx88909`'s approach I am now using the following code:

```
Private Sub dgvViewOrders_RowsAdded(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewRowsAddedEventArgs) Handles dgvViewOrders.RowsAdded
        Try

            Debug.Print("Processing Row: " & e.RowIndex)

            If dgvViewOrders.Columns.Contains("ColImg") = False Then
                Dim ColImage As DataGridViewImageColumn = New DataGridViewImageColumn
                ColImage.Name = "ColImg"
                dgvViewOrders.Columns.Add(ColImage)
                ColImage.HeaderText = "Status"
                ColImage.ImageLayout = DataGridViewImageCellLayout.Zoom
                ColImage.AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.AllCells

            End If


            If dgvViewOrders.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells("DepositPaid").Value = False Then
                dgvViewOrders.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells("ColImg").Value = My.Resources.WaitingForDeposit_25

            ElseIf dgvViewOrders.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells("DepositPaid").Value = True And CDate(dgvViewOrders.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells("DateProcessed").Value).AddDays(20) < Now And dgvViewOrders.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells("AllMaterialsDelivered").Value = False Then
                dgvViewOrders.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells("ColImg").Value = My.Resources.ItemsRequireOrdering_25

            ElseIf dgvViewOrders.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells("AllMaterialsDelivered").Value = False Then
                dgvViewOrders.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells("ColImg").Value = My.Resources.WaitingForDelivery_25

            Else
                If dgvViewOrders.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells("FullPaid").Value = True Then
                    dgvViewOrders.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells("ColImg").Value = My.Resources.Checked_25
                Else
                    dgvViewOrders.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells("ColImg").Value = My.Resources.WaitingForPayment_25
                End If

            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
            Debug.Print(ex.Message)
        End Try

    End Sub
```

But there appears to be an issue where when an image is added, this causes the `RowAdded` event to fire again. I put a `debug.print` in and this is the output before the sub is never called again:

> Processing Row: 0,
>   Processing Row: 1,
>   Processing Row: 0,
>   Processing Row: 1

The first two rows show the correct images in the `DataGridView` but the rest show nothing (or the red cross for no image).

*Additional Notes:* The `DataGridView` is populated using the following code:

`dgvViewOrders.DataSource = dtOrders` - Where `dtOrders` is a datatable obtained from an Access database

**UPDATE 2**

I have tried the method of assigning the images to an array and loading them only when the row is visible to the user and it works. But when scrolling the `DataGridView` the response is awful. All of the images revert back to the "No Image Assigned" and it takes approx 2 to 3 seconds for all of the rows' status images to be drawn.

Am I missing something? Here's my code:

```
Private Sub dgvViewOrders_CellFormatting(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs) Handles dgvViewOrders.CellFormatting

If LoadingComplete = False Then Exit Sub
If dgvViewOrders.Rows(e.RowIndex).IsNewRow Then Return
If e.ColumnIndex <> 0 Then Return


If DirectCast(dgvViewOrders.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells("DepositPaid").Value, Boolean) = False Then
    dgvViewOrders.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells("ColImg").Value = StatusImages(2)

ElseIf DirectCast(dgvViewOrders.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells("DepositPaid").Value, Boolean) = True And
   CDate(dgvViewOrders.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells("DateProcessed").Value).AddDays(20) < Now And
   DirectCast(dgvViewOrders.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells("AllMaterialsDelivered").Value, Boolean) = False Then
    dgvViewOrders.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells("ColImg").Value = StatusImages(5)

ElseIf DirectCast(dgvViewOrders.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells("AllMaterialsDelivered").Value, Boolean) = False Then
    dgvViewOrders.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells("ColImg").Value = StatusImages(3)
Else
    If DirectCast(dgvViewOrders.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells("FullPaid").Value, Boolean) = True Then
        dgvViewOrders.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells("ColImg").Value = StatusImages(0)
    Else
        dgvViewOrders.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells("ColImg").Value = StatusImages(1)
    End If

End If
```

End Sub

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several preliminary things in the code posted:

**Turn on Option Strict**  This code will not compile:

```
If dgvViewOrders.Rows(i).Cells("DepositPaid").Value = False Then
```

`DataGridView` cells return/hold `Object` and you cannot compare `Object` with `Boolean`

Conceptually, dismiss the notion that `The data is held in a DataGridView` and therefore you "must" loop thru all the rows.  Since you are using a `DataSource`, the data resides there and the control is just the means of presenting a view of the data to the user.

In most cases it will be many, many times faster to act on the data than poking around a UI control. [This Q&A example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41066375/1070452), it was taking 17 seconds or so to do Some Stuff.  In that case, working with the data reduced the time to a matter of **milliseconds**.  There is much less to do here and it can all be done in an event.

Also, **your app is leaking**:

```
dgvViewOrders.Rows(i).Cells("ColImg").Value = My.Resources.WaitingForDelivery_25
```

This is creating a new image object *every time*.  Your 2000 rows do not need 2000 individual objects; all rows awaiting delivery can show the *same* image.  Furthermore, having created that object your code would need to dispose of any previous image (for instance, when the status change).

---

To avoid leaks, load the images into an array:

```
' form level declatation
Private ImgBalls As Image()
... 
' elsewhere, load the images from resources:
ImgBalls = New Image() {
                        My.Resources.ballblack, My.Resources.ballblue,
                        My.Resources.ballgreen,
                        My.Resources.ballorange, My.Resources.ballpurple,
                        My.Resources.ballred, My.Resources.ballyellow
                        }
```

For assigning the image, you could iterate all the rows in the DataSource and set a code indicating the status, but even better in this case is to use one of the DGV events.  There are 2 good candidates:  `RowPrePaint` and `CellFormatting`.  Both are efficient: if the user never scrolls to row 1565, the code to act on it never runs.

This code also uses an `Enum` to index the images (`Status.Blue`) rather than magic numbers:

```
Private Sub dgv1_CellFormatting(sender As Object,..etc etc

    ' exit if the new user row, or not the ImgCol
    If dgv1.Rows(e.RowIndex).IsNewRow Then Return
    If e.ColumnIndex <> 8 Then Return

    If DirectCast(dgv1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells("Value").Value, Int32) <= 3 Then
        dgv1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells("ImgCol").Value = ImgBalls(Status.Green)

    ElseIf DirectCast(dgv1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells("Animal").Value, String) = "rat" Then
        dgv1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells("ImgCol").Value = ImgBalls(Status.Black)

    ElseIf DirectCast(dgv1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells("Price").Value, Decimal) > 14.99 Then
        dgv1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells("ImgCol").Value = ImgBalls(Status.Purple)
    Else
        dgv1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells("ImgCol").Value = ImgBalls(Status.Yellow)
    End If
End Sub
```

The good thing about using events for something like this, is the code only acts on the rows which the user looks at.  When the time to do the processing is broken up into bits, it is harder to notice.

Results:

[image]

Because the code assigns the same image object for all those using the Blue image/status, it no longer leaks resources.

---

Performance with various scroll methods:

[image]

I added another boolean column to more closely emulate the tests/conditions you show in the code.  It also uses a default question mark image in place of the standard "broken" image.  The animation shows a) using the down thumb, b) mouse wheel and then c) dragging the thumb.  There is a slight delay with the last one to allow as many as 10 rows to paint, but no where near 2-3 seconds (even with the laggy presentation of animated GIFs in posts - downloaded to run locally and it is snappier).

That said, there are some things you can do to optimize the code:

- Use `AndAlso` rather than `And` (and also use `OrElse` rather than `Or`) for boolean tests.  These will short circuit and not evaluate the other conditions once one fails.
- Leverage that in the order of test conditions.  For instance, in the second set, I would test `DepositPaid` and `AllMaterialsDelivered` first so that if either is false, no hokey-pokey with a date is needed (I would not expect that to make a major difference, but converting the bool seems like it should be simpler and faster than date stuff).

On balance, you might have something else somewhere eating up time.  The code for the animated image was similar to this:

```
' exit if the new user row, or not the ImgCol
If dgv1.Rows(e.RowIndex).IsNewRow Then Return
If e.ColumnIndex <> 9 Then Return

If DirectCast(dgv1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells("Active").Value, Boolean) = False Then
    dgv1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells("ImgCol").Value = ImgBalls(Status.Green)

ElseIf DirectCast(dgv1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells("Active").Value, Boolean) = True AndAlso
    DirectCast(dgv1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells("Delivered").Value, Boolean) = False AndAlso
    DirectCast(dgv1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells("ItemDate").Value, DateTime).AddDays(20) > DateTime.Now Then

    dgv1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells("ImgCol").Value = ImgBalls(Status.Purple)

ElseIf DirectCast(dgv1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells("Price").Value, Decimal) > 14.99 Then
    dgv1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells("ImgCol").Value = ImgBalls(Status.Orange)
Else
    If DirectCast(dgv1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells("Value").Value, Int32) < 5 Then
        dgv1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells("ImgCol").Value = ImgBalls(Status.Yellow)
    Else
        dgv1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells("ImgCol").Value = ImgBalls(Status.Blue)
    End If
End If
```

Comment: Good point on the images. Hadn't considered that the application would be leaking.

Comment: @plutonix, I have given your method a go, please see updated answer. And thanks for helping me again! You've helped me out a few times now!

Comment: just thinking about this again, could I set a default image in the column and run this on a background worker? I wouldn't lose responsiveness whilst scrolling then, and the image I could load as default could be a "Getting Status" image for example?

Comment: You could set a default image - perhaps one that covers the most likely condition. You cannot use a BGW though - you can work with controls only on the main UI thread. There are many ways to scroll, there is only a delay for me (no where near a matter of seconds) in one  of them, I am not sure how you are scrolling. As the answer explains, you *can* loop thru the DataTable and set them all upfront, but of the user can edit one of the values used to determine the status you still need event code to handle changes.

Comment: I updated the answer with 1 or 2 things you could do.  Overall it doesnt seem like *that code* is should result in the delay.  ("2-3 secs" is quite a long time for 20-30 rows to draw one cell)

Comment: I've made some changes as described by your answer and also reduced the size of the DGV to only 10 rows. the first 3 or 4 rows update quickly, but the rest take about 1 second now. Not nearly as quick as your example. Perhaps its the machine I'm on, I don't know. Also, how did you set the default "?" image?

Comment: The number of columns wont matter - you have is set to run only for Col(0) (I use col 8).  `imgCol.DefaultCellStyle.NullValue` will define the default image.  If the status is static - the user cannot change the value in any of those columns which determine the status - then you could loop thru the datatable and set the value there and skip all painting.  But my guess is that you have some code somewhere that is the cause - maybe some *other* code to loop thru the DGV rows.

Comment: Assuming the img col is one you added (not a real DB col), code to do DB Updates when *any* cell changes would be an example - that code should perform an early exit when it is that ImgCol.  Its a bit hard to debug code you dont have,

Answer (score 1):

As stated by the OP, the event is firing multiple times and only for rows 1 and 2 when using the `RowAdded` method. After some research I found [this](http://www.vbdotnetforums.com/ado-net/29000-rowsadded-event-doesn-t-fire-all-rows.html), in particular this comment:

> **Question:** Does the rowsadded event always fire for each row?
>
> **Answer**: No. It's called event coalescing and it would be very tedious and processor intensive to fire events every time one of thousands of trivial actions occurs.. In fact, methods (BeginLoadData/EndLoadData) exist to turn off event firing entirely, as it just slows everything down.

Instead I have looked at the [RowStateChanged](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.rowstatechanged(v=vs.110).aspx) method:

```
Private Sub DataGridView1_RowStateChanged(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewRowStateChangedEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.RowStateChanged

    If DataGridView1.Columns.Contains("ColImg") = False Then
        Dim ColImage As DataGridViewImageColumn = New DataGridViewImageColumn
        ColImage.Name = "ColImg"
        DataGridView1.Columns.Add(ColImage)
        ColImage.HeaderText = "Status"
        ColImage.ImageLayout = DataGridViewImageCellLayout.Zoom
        ColImage.AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.AllCells

    End If

    If e.StateChanged = DataGridViewElementStates.Displayed Then
        Debug.Print("Processing row: " & e.Row.Index.ToString)

        DataGridView1.Rows(e.Row.Index).Cells("ColImg").Value = My.Resources.Image1
    End If

End Sub
```

This is how I am loading the data:

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    _dt = New DataTable

    DataGridView1.DataSource = _dt

    Using con As New SqlConnection(connection),
          com As New SqlCommand(command, con)

        con.Open()
        _dt.Load(com.ExecuteReader)
    End Using

End Sub
```

> Note that I am assigning `_dt` to `DataGridView1.DataSource` before filling it. By doing this the event fires as expected.

This is a screenshot of my image (I appreciate it's rubbish but had to mock something up quickly):

[image]

This is how your code would look:

```
Private Sub dgvViewOrders_RowStateChanged(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewRowStateChangedEventArgs) Handles dgvViewOrders.RowStateChanged

    If DataGridView1.Columns.Contains("ColImg") = False Then
        Dim ColImage As DataGridViewImageColumn = New DataGridViewImageColumn
        ColImage.Name = "ColImg"
        DataGridView1.Columns.Add(ColImage)
        ColImage.HeaderText = "Status"
        ColImage.ImageLayout = DataGridViewImageCellLayout.Zoom
        ColImage.AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.AllCells

    End If

    If e.StateChanged = DataGridViewElementStates.Displayed Then

        If dgvViewOrders.Rows(e.Row.Index).Cells("DepositPaid").Value = False Then
            dgvViewOrders.Rows(e.Row.Index).Cells("ColImg").Value = My.Resources.WaitingForDeposit_25

        ElseIf dgvViewOrders.Rows(e.Row.Index).Cells("DepositPaid").Value = True And CDate(dgvViewOrders.Rows(e.Row.Index).Cells("DateProcessed").Value).AddDays(20) < Now And dgvViewOrders.Rows(e.Row.Index).Cells("AllMaterialsDelivered").Value = False Then
            dgvViewOrders.Rows(e.Row.Index).Cells("ColImg").Value = My.Resources.ItemsRequireOrdering_25

        ElseIf dgvViewOrders.Rows(e.Row.Index).Cells("AllMaterialsDelivered").Value = False Then
            dgvViewOrders.Rows(e.Row.Index).Cells("ColImg").Value = My.Resources.WaitingForDelivery_25

        Else
            If dgvViewOrders.Rows(e.Row.Index).Cells("FullPaid").Value = True Then
                dgvViewOrders.Rows(e.Row.Index).Cells("ColImg").Value = My.Resources.Checked_25
            Else
                dgvViewOrders.Rows(e.Row.Index).Cells("ColImg").Value = My.Resources.WaitingForPayment_25
            End If

        End If
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, the issue I am having with this is the column `ColImg` is created after the dataset is loaded, if I create it before, it's removed when the dataset is loaded. The code then fails when the image is attempted to be set because the column doesn't exist yet :(

Comment: please see updated question. I can't add the column to the datatable because the column must be a `DataGridViewImageColumn` type

Comment: @SilverShotBee actually I've just mocked up and I'm getting the same error. I'll do some testing.

Comment: Appreciate the help, I'll also be working on finding a solution!